# Keep texture shadeless, but receive shadows?

Tags: texturing, light, image, shaders, shadows

I'm working on a VFX shot where I have created a clean plate that is motion tracked to go over a store sign. I made some 3D text to put in its place, but because the clean plate is shadeless, the text does not cast a shadow on the clean plate. Is there a way to keep the material/texture shadeless and therefore seamless with the original video, and allow it to receive shadows?[image: Original Footage]
[image: Altered Sign]
[image: Combined Image]

Comment: This BlenderGuru tutorial describes a method that should work very well I think: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wjWoglMYXBE

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know if there is a way to do exactly what you're talking about, but I have another idea.

I would duplicate the clean plate and move it ever so lightly closer to the camera (as little as possible). Then change its material to a transparent shadow-catcher. That way, you can see the plate through/behind it, but the letters can still cast shadows on it.

I'd love to see how well it works ;-)

I hope that helps!

Comment: It totally worked! The Final image is at http://imgur.com/5dE8ZYq. Thanks so much for your help!